# SF Novel which is almost a John Carter of Mars Clone, man taught to swordfight gets taken to Mars on a teleportation experiment

Tags: story-identification, novel, pulp

Just to be clear, this novel is not in any way related to Edgar Rice Burroughs or Barsoom. It was clearly a knock-off meant to cash in on the popularity of ERB's books.

I remember the following about the novel:

It had an off-white cover with a man fighting a green martian (but not an ERB green martian).

The novels production value seemed like a pulp-reprint, even though I read it in the 1980s. Probably reprinted in the 1970s, or so I thought at the time.

Plot points:

- Man grows up next door to a French fencing master that teaches him how to sword fight.
- He takes part in a teleportation experiment that takes him to Mars.
- Adventures ensue, including a gladiatorial fight where the hero has to stall for time, so he slowly cuts his less-skilled opponent into hamburger.
- Runs into an issue where he cannot marry the girl of his dreams if he kills her fiance. Some cultural taboo.
- He eventually returns to Earth with only a few seconds passing, but coming back with scars from his adventure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be *Warriors of Mars* by "Edward Powys Bradbury", later republished as *City of the Beast* by Michael Moorcock.

It begins a trilogy featuring Michael Kane, an incarnation of Moorcock's Eternal Champion.
The trilogy is:

1. *Warriors of Mars / City of the Beast*
2. *Blades of Mars / Lord of the Spiders*
3. *Barbarians of Mars / Masters of the Pit*

[image: book cover, man jumping on a blue alien]

[image: book cover, alien gets speared by man]

[image: book cover, man faces an alien riding an alien beast]

Comment: beat me to the answer by 2 minutes

Comment: Yes, this is the one. A bit of research turned up some character names I recognized. Oddly, I never knew it was a Moorcock novel. Learn something new every day.

Comment: Wow, never knew Moorcock used such a ridiculous pseudonym!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the Michael Kane series by Michael Moorcock (as Edward P Bradbury).

1. *Warriors of Mars* (1965)
    aka *The City of the Beast*
2. *Blades of Mars* (1965)
    aka *Lord of the Spiders*
3. *Barbarians of Mars* (1965)
    aka *Masters of the Pit*

I had an omnibus of this trilogy with the stories all named under the alternate titles listed above but I'm buggered if I can find the book.  [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1531151.Warrior_of_Mars) shows the cover of the copy I had.